# Outputting an average figure from multiple sliders in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode5

I'm a beginner in Objective-C, and I would like to know how to output an average value with the value data from multiple sliders, to a label.

I went this far:

## .h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *Slider;
- (IBAction)updateValue:(UISlider *)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *persentage;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *Slider2;
- (IBAction)updateValue2:(UISlider *)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *persentage2;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *averagePercentage;


@end
```

## .m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)updateValue:(UISlider *)sender {
    _percentage.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f %%",sender.value*100];
}
- (IBAction)updateValue2:(UISlider *)sender {
    _percentage2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f %%",sender.value*100];
}

@end
```

What I want to do is, I want to make the "averagePercentage" label show the average percentage of the two inputs. What should I do? I am using the storyboard too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a method to your view controller and invoke it from your to IBActions:

```
@interface ViewController ()
- (void)updateAveragePercentage;
- (NSString *)stringForPercentage:(float)value;
@end

@implementation ViewController
...

- (IBAction)updateValue:(UISlider *)sender {
    self.percentage.text = [self stringForPercentage:sender.value];
    [self updateAveragePercentage];
}
- (IBAction)updateValue2:(UISlider *)sender {
    self.percentage2.text = [self stringForPercentage:sender.value];
    [self updateAveragePercentage];
}

- (void)updateAveragePercentage
{
    float average = 0.5f * (self.Slider.value + self.Slider2.value);
    self.averagePercentage.text = [self stringForPercentage:average];
}

- (NSString *)stringForPercentage:(float)value
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f %%", value * 100];
}

@end
```

Note that I declared `updateAveragePercentage` in the class extension declaration in your .m file, as it isn't necessary to make it publicly visible.

I also added a `stringForPercentage` method so that the `stringWithFormat` code isn't duplicated. You may want to consider using an [NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead of stringWithFormat to get better control and localization for your number formatting.

Comment: You could probably use the same action method for both sliders and do it all in one method.